# Creating Events in Powershell

Tags: powershell, object, properties, event-handling, propertychanged

The Task:

I'm writing a script that makes changes to an AD Object (user account) in sequential order:

1. Name change
2. Group add
3. Demographics change
4. Manager name added
5. Add email address

The problem:

I want a way to notify the next process in the sequence to start after confirming that the previous process has taken place.  The best solution I've been able to write is a loop that constantly checks for a "version" count increment on the DC where I'm making the change.  What I'd prefer to do is make a change to an object's attribute, have the version count increment trigger a "change" event that I subscribe to which would then trigger the next function\task in the sequence to begin.

I've tried searching the net for all sorts of ways to "watch" for a property change on an object, but I can't seem to find how to do that.  Anyone have any good starting points?  or Suggestions on how I can use events in combination with property changes on PowerShell objects that do not have an event class member?  This is not for a GUI.  Just a basic script.

Comment: Look at using PowerShell jobs.

Comment: Powershell is written in c# so if you do not find info under powershell you can always convert the c# samples.  See : https://learn-powershell.net/2013/02/08/powershell-and-events-object-events/?force_isolation=true  The link references Net Library.

Comment: Setting up change notifications sounds like extreme overkill for this. Why not just write a simple script that does all 5 actions? Why is it important that it's event-driven?

Comment: As Mathias says, there's no need to make these changes sequentially. Do them all. Write your script to trap any errors and if you need to check that they've changed, simply use a specific Domain Controller and make sure you both read and write to that specific controller using the `-Server` parameter on `Get-AdUser / Set-AdUser`.

Comment: My first attempt at writing the script, I did all five things, but it was bloated.  I recently re-wrote the script and it behaves much in the way that Mathias & Scepticalist suggest.  However, I'm thinking back to my original attempt at writing this script as it always bugged me that there wasn't an obvious way to capture the change of any property especially for objects that didn't have events.  So this question is more about solving cases where there would be a need for an event driven process.  After I wrote this question, I looked into C# conversions through add-Type. Is the only solution?